# Adding SoundTouch to Xcode/iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I've downloaded the [SoundTouch](http://www.surina.net/soundtouch/)  folder from their website and now I don't know what to do with it. I'm trying to integrate the pitch-manipulation feature into an iOS app that allows the user to select a song from their library and change the pitch.

What do I need to include in the Xcode project from the SoundTouch folder, and where do I go from there? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If it comes as a static library or framework, drag it into your project and show Xcode where it's headers are, if not, just drag in the source.  It's in C++, so it'll work perfectly.

Comment: Okay, where do I show Xcode the headers? I apologize for sounding like a n00b, I'm relatively new to Xcode. The other part of this issue is: Where do I initialize the features for the audio, the HTML file or one of the .h or .m files? I'm using PhoneGap, by the way.

Comment: @kylesimmonds, have you ever chance to integrate it with iOS? I'm facing an issue with SoundTouch.

Comment: @hagile, sorry, but this project was so long ago I no longer have the source files or the memory of how I managed it. I rarely develop in Xcode these days.

Answer (score 2):

If you still need it to use SoundTouch in your iOS project, I have share a GitHub repository with that libraries compiled for `armv7`, `armv7s`, `arm64`, `i386` and `x86_64`

https://github.com/enrimr/soundtouch-ios-library

To implement that compiled library in your project, you have to add SoundTouch directory (which includes libSoundTouch.a and the directory with headers) in your Xcode project and then include

```
#include "SoundTouch.h"
```

in your controller file.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Can you please post a few lines as to how to initiate the SoundTouch instance and how to load audio in it?

Answer (score 1):

I found this question googling "building soundtouch in Xcode"

It seems there is a project on github that has completed this successfully, https://github.com/mwhagedorn/SoundTouch

I was able to clone the repository, build the project, and include the libSoundTouch.a file in my project.

So you will need to include the soundtouch.h in the objective c file you want to access it from. From there create an instance of soundtouch, i.e. SoundTouch audioEngine = SoundTouch.createInstance();, and go from there.